# Как получить весь код страницы?

Tags: javascript

Можно с помощью `innerHTML` получить весь код страницы? Или ещё с помощью чего нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
   alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
};
```

Когда всё загрузится тогда и получайте а не во время обработки как у некоторых приведённых здесь других ответов, а вообще погуглите onDOMLoad чтоб не ждать загрузки картинрк и т.д

Answer (score 3):

```
$("html").html();
```

или на чистом JS

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: на чистом js, без всяких jquery

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: пробовал, не работает

Comment: все отлично работает, что у Вас не работает?

Comment: var cod = document.documentElement.innerHTML;  переменная cod у меня содержит первый элемент между тегами <head>

Comment: а нужно чтоб весь код страницы был

Comment: все работает нормально, поместите код в боди

Answer (score 0):

[ответ здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/HCZpv/)

```
var doc = document || window.document;  
alert(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: это если dom нужен

Comment: @ilyas а вы в курсе когда выполняется ваш код?

Comment: ну он же не написал когда ему нужно, конечно корректнее всего его вызывать при body onLoad, а так я кинул тупо кусок кода который выводит dom страницы и все.

Comment: ...так вот он выполняется `onLoad` (т.е. window.onload) т.к. вы выбрали это наверху слева а вот если выбрать `load` в head'е то [код будет работать не корректно](http://jsfiddle.net/qKxrD/) поэтому ТС сначала должен знать **когда** исполняется его код и тогда такие вопросы отпадут сами собой imho...

Comment: Учту в след раз, Я прикинул человек в курсе что выводить нечего если не загрузился документ.

Answer (score 0):

А как же `doctype`?
Если человеку нужно скопировать всю страницу, то `doctype` тоже нужен.

```
var node = document.doctype;
var doctypeHtml = "<!DOCTYPE "
         + node.name
         + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>';
var result = doctypeHtml + document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

код позаимствован с **[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript)**

Answer (score -1):

при чем тут `body`? Между

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert(html);
</script>
```

нужно размещать. Желательно в теге `head`.

Comment: и так понятно что скрипты нужно размещать в теге    `<script/>`   . А на счет  head, не факт если в документе будет много элементов, то все они (ноды) успеют загрузится